# Codeigniter : Varnish and Cookie / Session conflict

Tags: php, session, caching, varnish

I have a website which is dependent on session and cookie. I want to get Varnish cache implemented on it.

1. When the browser is open the website has same session id, till the browser is closed. But the **AGE** value in header remains **0** . This AGE value describes if varnish is caching the page or not. 0 means its not caching.
2. To check Varnish caching is working or not, **`curl -I domainname`** is the command, I hit this through terminal, The header gives **different PHPSESSIONID** on every HIT and the value of AGE also remains 0.

Can't exactly determine as in what is not allowing site to be cached by Varnish.

Just to test I **`commented the session_start()`**, and here are the following observation.
On Browser

1. The session id cookie was not created in browser.
2. AGE still remained 0 for several hits on same page.

On Terminal

1. The php session id was not shown in header response.
2. Age value was 0 on first hit, but on later hits it kept getting incremental numeric value.

It seems that Varnish fails to cache on browser hits. Specially when Domain is specified.

Any Help How get the varnish cache working for session based website ?

Answer (score 0):

Varnish does not cache pages that set cookies by default. There are two ways around this issue:

1. Strip cookies from the page. This will only work for you if the page does not require a session in the first place (i.e. it has no user-specific content). You can do so like so:

   ```
   // ... default.vcl
   sub vcl_recv {
     unset req.http.Cookie;

     return(hash);
   }
   ```
2. Add the cookie to the hash generated by Varnish, which will then mean every session will have it's own individual cache (it'll still benefit performance, but nowhere near as significantly as if you can go for option 1. Like so:

   ```
   // ... default.vcl
   sub vcl_hash {
     hash_data(req.url);

     if (req.http.host) {
       hash_data(req.http.host);
     } else {
       hash_data(server.ip);
     }

     hash_data(req.http.Cookie);

     return(lookup);
   }
   ```

You may have some pages that appear to have no user-specific content on (like say you have a blog, blog posts wouldn't need user-specific content) but you may have something that indicates whether or not the user is logged in. If you can make that happen over AJAX to a non-cached, or per-session cached endpoint then it'll all work fine.

With option 2, you may find you need to store the Cookie temporarily in another header so that Varnish actually caches the page, you can do so like this:

```
// ... default.vcl
sub vcl_recv {
  set req.http.X-Cookie = req.http.Cookie;
  unset req.http.Cookie;

  return(hash);
}
```

Then simply alter the `vcl_hash` function to use `req.http.X-Cookie` instead of `req.http.Cookie`.

Comment: I tried the 2nd option , edited default.vcl.
and commented the `session_start()`. Thus the sessions are not created. 
Hit the URL on browser. here is the response :
`Accept-Ranges 
bytes
Age 
0
Cache-Control 
max-age=3600
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Wed, 22 Apr 2015 17:59:57 GMT
Expires 
Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma 
cache
Server 
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding 
chunked
Via 
1.1 varnish-v4
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.3.3
X-Varnish 
21`

**AGE = 0**  on several hits. Seems it dint work when hit is on browser.

Comment: The issue there is your expires header. It is in the past, therefore Varnish will not cache it. PHP sets some of it's own headers, because it likes to think it's being helpful. Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: I tried hit on terminal with `curl -I domainname`, here is the response :

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Apr 2015 18:01:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Pragma: cache
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Varnish: 98369 32857
Age: 87
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Content-Length: 28357
Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: Looks like caching worked on that last comment you've put in, notice the age header?

Comment: Oh, one thing you may find useful if you've not already noticed it yet, is that when Varnish does successfully cache something, you'll see the `X-Varnish` header have 2 numeric values, instead of one.

Comment: The Age that have value was when the domain was hit on terminal and not on browser.
I tried `session_cache_limiter('public')` header:
`Accept-Ranges bytes Age 0 Cache-Control
max-age=3600
Connection 
keep-alive
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Wed, 22 Apr 2015 18:20:20 GMT
Expires 
Wed, 22 Apr 2015 21:20:20 GMT
Last-Modified 
Wed, 22 Apr 2015 18:20:16 GMT
Pragma 
cache
Server 
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Set-Cookie 
PHPSESSID=nulpp2aahui6hsod16jrsapss1; expires=Wed, 29-Apr-2015 18:20:20 GMT; path=/
Transfer-Encoding 
chunked
Via 
1.1 varnish-v4
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.3.3
X-Varnish 
622594`

Comment: I checked the importance of **X-Varnish** , 2 numeric values are the ID of the current request and ID of request which created the cache, I the case when the AGE remains 0 the X-Varnish will have only one ID i.e of current request. Thus when the sites is accessed via browser, the X-Varnish has only one ID value, which means cache is not getting created.

Comment: Okay, the issue you have on that page from before, is that it has the set-cookie header. It won't cache the page with that.

Comment: On my website I did this **1**. index.php : the whole site process starts from this page , this had session_start(), which is now removed. **2**. I have page called Ajax.php, which is written just to handle a login ajax call. This page has session_start(). When user is not loggedIN, session_start() is not started from index.php nor ajax php. Varnish caches the page when hit on browser. Now if I browse it should cache other pages too right? But it doesn't. What I noticed is **Cookie _gat & _ga (google analytics cookie)** are created.Does this block varnish to cache site when hit is on browser?

Comment: You need to ensure that Varnish is stripping the Cookie, as shown in my answer. This won't matter to GA, as it'll still be there in your browser, and it'll be able to use it just fine.

Comment: I have made the changes to avoid cookies in varnish. 
Now I don't have the session and cookie available on index.php and its available in ajaxcall php file. Scenario :

1. The user gets a login option. He logs in and ajax call is executed which creates a cookie for the user. This cookie is a serialized array and its encrypted.

2. Now user browse to page / refresh same page. I have to hit the ajax call to check the user login status. It check the cookie and and decrypt it. 
But till the ajax call return response, Login option is visible. Though user had already loggedin. Any other way around ?

Comment: Have a loading state, with a spinner or something that indicates that you're still waiting for information to determine whether or not the user is logged in.

Comment: I can't have that. Just to show the user name on right corner. My website is a high end data site. Where all data is based on location and events , which is loaded fine.
I was thinking to encrypt and decrypt the user info in Javascript itself But that will create a security issue. So hitting server is must. 
An on page load, enabling session n cookie will not allow varnish to cache page when hitting through browser. And testing this in Ajaxcalls gives a lag. 


 Any other alternative ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of unfortunately. Sorry. Perhaps Varnish is not the right tool for the job in this case, and you'd benefit from something more integrated with your application, like Redis or Memcached?